# Purescript version change issue

Tags: npm, npm-install, purescript

My current purescript version is 0.11.7, I would like to change it to 0.12.0. I have tried uninstalling using `npm uninstall -g purescript` and it gets successfully uninstalled but still `purs --version` gives `0.11.7`. I have also tried running `npm install -g purescript@0.12.0` and it does get successfully installed but still `purs --version` gives `0.11.7`. Please help!

Comment: assuming you are on linux: what does `which purs` and `where purs` tell you? Usually it's an issue where you have to older one with prio in your path (`where` give you two with the npm/bin directory after some global one like `usr/bin`) - in this case just delete the one `purs` you don't want (e.g. the one in `/usr/bin`) - aside from that you can (if you like) always use Purescript project-locally ( `npm install --save-dev purescript`) and use `npx purs` to access this one over the global one - I'd recommend doing this (this way you can stick with older purs/projects too if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed the package globally via yarn. Try `yarn global remove purescript`